# How to get single string result from stored procedure in .NET Core 3.0

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I have a stored procedure that returns a string value based on conditions, and it has or 4 parameters. I face challenge in executing the stored procedure and retrieving the result.

I find everywhere that returns results from insert queries from same model. Kindly share your suggestions for this.

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_test]
    (@param1 INT, 
     @param2 NVARCHAR(100),
     @param3 INT,
     @param4 NVARCHAR(50))   
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@param1 = '')
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'ok' AS output
    END
    ELSE 
        SELECT 'not ok' AS output
END
```

Please suggest how to get this query result using Entity Framework Core 3.0 `DbContext`.

The error I get when I try using `.FromSqlRaw`:

> FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling `AsEnumerable` after the FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated method to perform the composition on the client side.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: IgnoreQueryFilters() does get fix this issue. But between without using entity can get store procedure result to string  in Entity Frameowrk CORE 3.0 ??

Comment: Can you  pls show how you tried using .FromSqlRaw?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite it as :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_test](@param1 INT,@param2 NVARCHAR(100),@param3 INT,@param4 NVARCHAR(50), @STR_OUT NVARCHAR(256) OUTPUT)     
AS

BEGIN

    IF (@param1='')
    BEGIN
        SET @STR_OUT ='ok';
    END
    else
        SET @STR_OUT = 'not ok';
```

And read the OUTPUT value of the last parameter.

Comment: I  want to know how to retrieve it using DB CONTEXT